# How can I increase the SMTP email file size?

Tags: 7, emails

I have a drupal 7 website with rules 7.x-2.13. There is a rule which sends html email with all the fields whenever a new node is created of a content type. There is a file field as well which allows user to upload PDF docs of max size 20MB
But whenever user uploads  file greater than 8MB rule to send html email doesn't go ( although the node is saved) there is an error:
message file too big
client denied by server configuration: /var/www/drupal/.env

How can I increase this size?

Exchange server is configured so that users can send email attachment max size 50 MB.

Comment: in email, include file url, not the file

Comment: or just fix your server configuration like the error said ...